# Total variation between two measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, total-variation

Let $p_0, p_1$ be two densities with corresponding measures $P_0, P_1$ such that $d_{TV} (P_0, P_1) > 0$. Define set of measures $B = \left \{ P : d_{TV}(P, P_1) \leq \frac{d_{TV}(P_0, P_1)}{2} \right\}$. I want to prove that $\int_{p_1 > p_0} (p - p_0) \geq \frac{d_{TV}(P_0, P_1)}{2}$ where is p is a density corresponding to $P\in B$.

So far, I have tried decomposing the set $\{p_1 > p_0\}$ to write out the integral but have not gotten anywhere.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What does $p_1 > p_0$ stand for? How do you compare two measures? I know the partial ordering $P > Q$ is $Q$ is absolutely continuous relative to $P$ but I don't think you are using this one.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. By $p_1 > p_0$, I meant the set $\{x: p_1(x) > p_0(x)\}$, so $\int_{p_1 > p_0} (p-p_0) = \int_{\{x:p_1(x) > p_0(x)\}} (p(x) - p_0(x)) dx$.

Comment: Your comment made the expression _less sensical._ $p_1$ and $p_0$ are measures, so they are defined on sets. Now, assuming this at face value, $\{x : p_1(x) > p_0(x)\}$ is a set of sets...

Comment: I think I have abused the notation in my question. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma 1:** $\int\limits_{p_0 > p_1} (p_1 - p_0) = \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p_0 - p_1).$

*Proof.* Since $p_0$ and $p_1$ integrate to one on $\mathbf{R}^d,$ we see
$$
0 = \int\limits_{\mathbf{R}^d} (p_1-p_0) = \int\limits_{p_1 - p_0 \neq 0}(p_1 - p_0)
$$
and the result follows since $\{p_1 - p_0 \neq 0\} = \{p_1 > p_0\} \cup \{p_0 > p_1\}.$ Q.E.D.

**Lemma 2:** $d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P_0, P_1) = \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p_1-p_0).$

*Proof.* If we show that any Borel set $A$ satisfies
$$
\int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p_0 - p_1) \leq P_1(A) - P_0(A) \leq \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p_1 - p_0)
$$
then $d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P_0, P_1) \leq \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p_1 - p_0)$ and the equality would follow by taking the Borel set $A = \{p_1 > p_0\}.$ Thus, suffices to show the aforementioned condition. Now, if $A$ is any Borel set,
$$
P_1(A) - P_0(A) = \int\limits_A (p_1 - p_0) = \int\limits_{A \cap \{p_1 > p_0\}} (p_1 - p_0) + \int\limits_{A \cap \{p_0 > p_1\}} (p_1 - p_0) \leq \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p_1 - p_0)
$$
since, on the set $A \cap \{p_1 > p_0\} \subset \{p_1 > p_0\}$ the integrand is positive and on $A \cap \{p_1 < p_0\}$ the integrand is negative. For the reverse inequality, we show similarly
$$
P_1(A) - P_0(A) = \int\limits_{A \cap \{p_0 > p_1\}} (p_1 - p_0) \geq \int\limits_{p_0 > p_1} (p_1 - p_0) = \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p_0 - p_1)
$$
where intequality follows from the negativity of the integrand on the region of integration and the last equality follows form lemma 1. Q.E.D.

**Proof of the exercise.** Write
$$
\int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p - p_0) = \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p - p_1 + p_1 - p_0) = \int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p - p_1) + d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P_0, P_1)
$$
by lemma 2. Clearly, $\int\limits_{p_1 > p_0} (p - p_1) \geq -d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P, P_1) \geq -\dfrac{d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P_0, P_1)}{2}.$ The desired result follows at once. Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you! I think the key observation for me in your derivation was $\int _{p_1 > p_0} (p- p_1) \geq -d_{TV} (P, P_1)$. I somehow could not see that.

Comment: It happens to everyone.